# Service running in docker container calling a web service running in another service in a different docker container

Tags: docker, networking

For sake of argument lets say I have 2 docker containers, container A and container B.  Container A has a service (service A) running inside of it.  Similarly, container B has a service (service B) running inside of it.  Service B exposes a web service interface on port 8082 and we have a port mapping -p 8082:8082 such that the outside world can make a web service call to service B (e.g. http://some_ip:8082/somemethod).  However, lets suppose that the service A needs to make the same web call to service B.  How would this be accomplished?  Is this even possible?

Note: I don't like the solution of Docker Compose.  This essentially requires multiple containers to have intimate knowledge of other containers.  Additionally, it requires all containers to be hosted in the same Docker engine.  This won't work in the real world.  Container A is owned by org A and container B is owned by org B.  I can access the web service running in container B from the outside world, but I can't access that same web method from container A.  That isn't good at all.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest choice: You can use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/), which [creates a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) between containers, so you can make your call from service A by reaching serviceB:8082. For example, your docker-compose.yml can look like:

```
serviceA:
    image: myImage

serviceB:
    image: myOtherImage
    ports:
        - "8082:8082"
```

Without docker-compose you can create a network manually and connect your containers:

```
docker network create myNetwork
# create containers for serviceA and serviceB...
docker network connect myNetwork serviceA
docker network connect myNetwork serviceB
```

Then your containers will be reachable each other by either the IP address or their alias. More information on networks here: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: Not quite enough information here.  I don't understand why service A needs to specify any ports.  So you're saying with the compose approach my web call would be http://serviceB:8082/someMethod?

Comment: I would also like to add, lets say these containers were on completely different VMs (as they would likely be in the real world), how would we accomplish this using compose.  Image A is owned by company A, and image B is owned by company B.

Comment: Yes. The port mapping from service A was a typo. The call should be serviceB:8082/someMethod. Also, the ports instruction is not needed if only serviceA will reach serviceB, as long as serviceB exposes port 8082. The port mapping in docker-compose.yml is towards your host.

Comment: For your second comment, that's a different question. If the containers are in isolated VMs, you'll have to open the ports in the VMs and make each other reachable over the network, just as you would with a simple server application.

Comment: The docker compose isn't a solution, its a hack to allow multiple services in multiple containers to have intimate knowledge of each other.  That should never be implemented, at least form a service perspective.  Docker appears to have dropped the ball on this.  In my case all services will be on the same network, but docker has no visibility into that network.  Docker fail.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to have to down vote this solution.  Its the type of hack good software development should avoid at all costs.  This should NEVER be implemented.

Comment: BTW, the network bridge doesn't work even when the containers are in the same Docker engine.